# Take pair dataset and orient it to move focus on left column for all unique values and show all pair combinations on the right despite direction

Tags: r, pivot

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
ID|col 1 | col2
 1 Apple   Banana
 2 Apple   Pear
 3 Orange  Apple
 4 Apple   Lemon
 5 Lemon   Banana
 6 Pear    Lemon
```

Would like to turn it like this

```
 ID|Col 1| col 2
 1  Apple  Banana
 2  Apple  Pear
 3  Apple  Orange
 4  Apple  Lemon
 5  Banana Apple
 6  Banana Lemon
 7  Pear   Apple
 8  Pear   Lemon
 9  Orange Apple
10  Lemon  Apple
11  Lemon  Banana
12  Lemon  Pear
```

Order does not matter, i would just like this type of arrangement.

Update**

Is there a way to keep corresponding ID?

```
     ID|Col 1| col 2
 1  Apple  Banana
 2  Apple  Pear
 3  Apple  Orange
 4  Apple  Lemon
 1  Banana Apple
 5  Banana Lemon
 2  Pear   Apple
 6  Pear   Lemon
 3  Orange Apple
 4  Lemon  Apple
 5  Lemon  Banana
 6  Lemon  Pear
```

Comment: `d2 = rbind(d[ , 2:3], setNames(d[ , 3:2], c("col1", "col2")))`; `d2[order(d2$col1, d2$col2), ]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    complete(col1 = unique(col1), col2 = unique(col2)) %>% 
    filter(col1 != col2)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
rbind(df1, df1[, .(ID, col2 = col1, col1 = col2)])
 ID   col1   col2
 1:  1  Apple Banana
 2:  2  Apple   Pear
 3:  3 Orange  Apple
 4:  4  Apple  Lemon
 5:  5  Lemon Banana
 6:  6   Pear  Lemon
 7:  1 Banana  Apple
 8:  2   Pear  Apple
 9:  3  Apple Orange
10:  4  Lemon  Apple
11:  5 Banana  Lemon
12:  6  Lemon   Pear
```

Comment: Hey is there a way to keep the ID's associated in the original unique pair as I have shown in the update?

Comment: @user35131 Are you just looking for this `bind_rows(df1, cbind(df1[1], setNames(df1[3:2], names(df1)[2:3])))`

Comment: i got this message. Error in setnames(x, value) : 
  Can't assign 2 names to a 3 column data.table

Comment: I would like to keep the previous lines of code with the associated id that the pair was involved in if possible.

Comment: @user35131 i thought you had a `data.frame`.  If it is data.table, it is easier, try `rbind(df1, df1[, .(ID, col2 = col1, col1 = col2)])`